# Call unmanaged code from c#. Getting data using IntPtr

Tags: c#, pinvoke, unmanaged, netapi32

I have a strange problem with application that I'm currently writing. I'm pretty sure i haven't changed anything within the below code recently, but somehow it stopped working. 
To the point.
I'm using:

```
[DllImport("NetApi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern uint NetShareGetInfo(
        string servername,
        string netname,
        int level,
        out IntPtr ppBuf
        );
```

To import **NetApi32.dll**. I need physical Path. **WMI and WinRM cannot be used.**
Then I have enum and struct as below:

```
public enum ShType
    {
        DiskTree = 0,
        PrintQ = 1,
        Device = 2,
        IPC = 3,
        Temporary = 0x40000000,
        Special = unchecked((int)0x80000000)
    }
    public struct SHARE_INFO_502
    {
        public string Name;
        public ShType Type;
        public string Remark;
        public int Permissions;
        public int MaxUses;
        public int CurrentUses;
        public string Path;
        public string PassWd;
        public int reserved;
        public IntPtr SecDescriptor;
    }
```

all in

```
 [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public static class SafeNativeMethods
```

Class according to VS code analyzer.
I call it with:

```
 IntPtr ptrGet;
 var resGetInfo = SafeNativeMethods.NetShareGetInfo("server_name", "share_name", 502, out ptrGet);             
 SafeNativeMethods.SHARE_INFO_502 siGet = (SafeNativeMethods.SHARE_INFO_502)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptrGet, typeof(SafeNativeMethods.SHARE_INFO_502));
```

after running above code I do not receive any errors or exceptions, however, **siGet** Struct has only first letter of each property value.
Where could be the problem?

Comment: See this for the declaration of SHARE_INFO_502 : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.SHARE_INFO_502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default character set is `Ansi`, and that's what the struct marshalling uses. But you opt for the Unicode version of the function. You should also specify the character set for the struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct SHARE_INFO_502
....
```

Some tips when marshalling text:

- Whenever you see only the first character of a string, you should first suspect that you have UTF-16 text interpreted as ANSI or UTF-8.
- Whenever you see text that looks Chinese where you expected English, you should first suspect that you have ANSI or UTF-8 text interpreted as UTF-16.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Indeed, character set was missing. I must have accidentally delete it while ago. I could have figure out by myself -
 silly me. Thanks for prompt response and the Tips - noted!